# Rails 6 number field with comma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

When a user inputs a number value into a field that contains a comma, for example: 1,000,000. When the form is submitted and saved, the value becomes 1. The column  type is a `t.bigint`

How do I prevent this across all my numeric fields?

Comment: While you can do something like the gsub solution below, IMO it is a brittle approach -- especially given that in Europe they often use commas to denote a number's scale, but the US uses decimal points. I would add a validation on the input field to ensure that acceptable input is numeric but implement field masking so it will _display_ with commas during input and still be readable to the user.

Comment: How do you add masking? Also, I have a validation of numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, less_than_or_equal_to: 100}, but it does not catch the commas

Comment: @Allison : Shouldn't the issue comma vs. period be decided by the locale?

Comment: @user2012677 : Maybe you can first use [number_with_delimiter](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html) to get a "normalized string" representing your number, and then simply use `to_i` on it to get your numeric value.

Comment: Does this post help? https://blog.makandra.com/2010/03/how-to-use-the-comma-as-decimal-separator-in-activerecord-columns-and-text-fields/

Comment: Are you aware that the meaning of `1.123` or `1,123` highly depends on the user's locale or the country they are from? Do you need to take of the different meanings or are you fine with just fixing it for a certain group of people and break it for all others?

Comment: @user2012677 Locale settings are the reason why I'm saying the gsub solution suggested by some people below is extremely brittle. The value is saving as 1 because `'1,000,000'.to_i` truncates everything after the first comma/decimal. Your app should enforce that the input is numeric -- not a string. I have no way of knowing how your project is set up or which technologies you're using. Field/input masking is something that you do on the front end, so you would want to google how to do that for whatever you're writing your front end in.

Comment: If you change your implementation to ensure that the number is stored as an integer at every step of the way (never a string), you can use something like `ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper#number_to_currency` to decorate it to a human-readable string for times that you need to expose the persisted value in the UI. On the front end, the field should _only_ accept integers, but you should use input masking to ensure the field's contents remain human-readable while the value is being entered (e.g., https://css-tricks.com/input-masking/).

Comment: I _do not_ recommend the 10 year old blog post referenced by @Thang. That approach is brittle and if you want to convert the values to European locale formats, you should be writing a Decorator that appropriately converts them.

Comment: @user1934428 Yes, but the problem is that the OP is doing something inadvisable by saving a string to an integer field; this is why it's truncating input at the first non-numeric value (e.g., `'12d3'.to_i` will evaluate to 12). They need to ensure the input format is numeric and then convert it to the appropriate locale if they want to later display it in the UI. With regard to input formatting, they need to implement field masking.

Answer (score 2):

The key thing about the thousand delimiter is that it will always be followed by three digits. So a regex lookahead would make sense. Also I'd do this processing in the controller rather than the model as it's a function of the input from the form.

So if I had an object `Foo` with a `some_number` attribute, in the foos controller I'd do something like:

```rb
def foo_params
  params.require(:foo).permit(:some_number).tap do |foo|
    foo[:some_number] = foo[:some_number]&.split(/[\.\,](?=\d{3})/).join
  end
end
```

That will convert "3,000" and "3.000" into "3000", but leave "3.12" as "3.12".

It will also convert "23,345,555,444.3" into "23345555444.3"

Comment: This is an extremely brittle suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's the best way to do this, but I usually use a custom setter, lets say your column is `total`, then I do something like:

```
def total=(value)
  value = value.gsub(/[\.,],'') if value.is_a?(String) # remove , and .
  write_attribute(:total, value)
end
```

Now you can assign anything like "1.000" or "2,343,111" and it will strip comma and dot.

If you want to be more permissive with the values (in french you could write "1 000"), you can use `/\D/` for the regexp to remove anything that's not a digit.

Comment: or `value.delete('.,') if...`.

Comment: This is an extremely brittle suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

When space ( ) or period (.) is used as a thousand separator and comma (,) as decimal separator, ie: "772 067,48". First it removes space, then period and replaces comma with period.

So not directly applicable to OPs question but I found the page through a search engine and others may do as well.

```
def foo_params
    params.require(:foo).permit(:year, :quarter, :first).tap do |foo|
    foo[:first] = foo[:first]&.gsub(' ', '').gsub('.', '').gsub(',', '.')
end
```